# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, Unity Dependency Resolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container, custom-membershipprovider

My `IUserService` is null, not sure what's going on.
This is my `AccountController`:

```
private readonly ICustomMembershipProvider _membershipProvider;

public AccountController(ICustomMembershipProvider provider)
{
     _membershipProvider = provider;
}
//other code omitted
```

My `CustomMembershipProvider`:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider, ICustomMembershipProvider
{
private IUserService _userService;

    public CustomMembershipProvider()
        : this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>())
    {
    }

    public CustomMembershipProvider(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
//other code omitted
```

When I try to register a user, and the following method is called, my `_userService` is null, and that's what is causing the error but not sure why it's happening.

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    var tempUser = _userService.GetByName(username);
//other code omitted
```

All other dependencies get resolved successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this answer since I spent multiple hours trying to figure out what this error was referring to. My Project had this warning: `Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly` , since it was a warning I didn't pay attention to it. Well, apparently that was the root of all problems, my `Project.Web` was using Mvc 3.0, while my `Project.Services` was using Mvc 4.0, this is why the `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>()` was not working. After I rolled back my `Project.Services` to Mvc 3.0, my entire solution worked like a charm! Lesson learned: pay attention to warnings.